# DOM implementation in java

Tags: java

In a web browser written in java different types of parser have been used to do the parsing and create a DOM document. In the process of rendering  how the browser visualize the DOM into J-Component . Can anyone tell me about the whole process of implementing of DOM into J-Component to show the whole web-page in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link where you can find how to display a DOM Hierarchy into JTree (subclass of JComponent) component:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/JAXPDOM4.html#wp64186

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

That is far too large a subject for this forum - Unless you restrict the browser to a specific version of HTML without CSS, without JavaScript (or other scripting languages) and without any embedded objects.

You could look at [existing code](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) if you can work within the GPL and other licences.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you implement the HTML and CSS standards. Doing so completely and correctly is a HUGE amount of work, several man-years at least. [There are](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) [some](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/06/16/jwebpane-bof-screenshots-javaone-2009) [projects](http://www.webrenderer.com/) are are attempting this, but none have been very successful so far.